# Reference request for: inverse of a non-singular M-matrix has all elements non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does anyone know the best (earliest?) reference please for the proof that the inverse of a non-singular M-matrix has all elements non-negative?

Comment: Probably you mean to specify in the question itself the *inverse* of a given non-singular $M$-matrix?   I don't usually rely on Wikipedia, but their entry might be helpful here.   The topic is at least a century old, so it's treated in most textbooks on matrix theory.   Maybe the question fits better at math.stackexchange.com?  (The "earliest" reference is pretty early, and the $M$ was apparently used in tribute to the work of Minkowski.)

Comment: Sorry, you're right, now fixed. As you say, it's an old topic. The result may be found in several places but I'd like to reference the original result if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You may wish to look at [Plemmons, R.J. (1977), LAA 18](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795%2877%2990073-8) and references therein.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Looking there and the refs given, Fiedler and Ptak 1962 provide a proof without referencing an earlier result, though earlier work by Ostrowski, Fan, Koteljansku and Minkowski are mentioned, and I imagine one of those probably proved this result earlier.

Comment: Fan 1958, Theorem 5' in "Topological proofs for certain theorems on matrices with non-negative elements..." is now the earliest reference I can find.